# Screen Capture APIs

Tags: computer-vision, aforge, emgucv

I'm working on a project that requires capturing a region of the desktop and stream images to be altered and processed in realtime. When I used Aforge, I get roughly 12 frames after processing and 28 before. I'm aware that my processing will drop the performance, but is the Screencapture feature of a forge really slow?  Would openCV be faster?  Is there a faster alternative?

Comment: mind, if i remove the opencv tag(unrelated) ?

Comment: I don't think its unrelated. I want to know if OpenCV yields better performance than aforge with screen capturing.

Comment: there's no screen capture functionality in opencv. if any, you must be talking about emgu, which again is a 3rd party c# wrapper around opencv. (so, still not related)

Comment: I was not aware of the difference. I'll look into that. Thank you.

Comment: but probably add an emgu tag instead...

Answer (score 0):

most likely others are faster because other parties use faster compression while sending you the data. Or try to send less data, for example divide the screen with 8 x 8 blocks, and only send those blocks that have changed in between.. things like that are often used in such apps.